# view permission if request data not in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view -

```
class File_List(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv
    serializer_class = cdx_compositesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
        model = get_model('markit', filename)
        filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')
        queryset = model.objects.using('markitdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
        return queryset
```

For now ignore that model is listed twice it's the same model I need to figure that out later.

For permissions, I want it to deny access if the following occurs.

I have an extended Auth in my models.py

```
class FileIndex(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    vendorid = models.IntegerField()
    vendorname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tablename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'file_index'
        verbose_name = 'File/Vendor Index'
        verbose_name_plural = 'File/Vendor Indicies'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class UserFile(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    fileid = models.ForeignKey(FileIndex)
    grant_date = models.DateTimeField()
    revoke_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_files'
        verbose_name = 'User File Matrix'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User File Matricies'
```

I want to be able to say that if the filename does not show up in relation to the user access will be denied.

In SQL it's simply a matter of returning the list of filenames the user has access to -

```
select * from auth_files af
inner join auth_user au on au.id = af.userid
inner join file_index fi on fi.id = af.fileid
where au.user = 'user logged in'
```

then I want to tell it that if that if the filename in the request is in the list of filenames returned from the above query then yes the user can do what they want to do.

update - tweaking like so -

```
class File_List(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv
    serializer_class = cdx_compositesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
#        authorized_files = UserFile.objects.filter(userid=self.request.user).values_list('fileid')
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
        model = get_model('markit', filename)
        filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')

        if FileIndex.objects.filter(filename=filename).exists():
            queryset = model.objects.using('markitdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
            return queryset
```

I now get the following error -

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you can check like this:

```
filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
if FileIndex.objects.filter(filename=filename).exists():
    #do something
```

Comment: updating my question I get   

'NoneType' object is not iterable now.

Comment: No sooner did I post I stripped down my example I understand the logic now so thank you!  This isn't exactly what I'll be doing but it pointed me in the right direction!